# Trying To Have A Header And Unordered List Item On Same Line

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have looked and looked, and tried different variations of CSS, but with no success thus far.

Not sure if this is even possible, but trying to have an H4 and content in the unordered list item.

I can add the H4 to the list item, but after the headline, the content keeps starting on the next line as shown in the "MOCKUP OF PROBLEM I KEEP GETTING EXAMPLE". I am trying to keep the content on the same line as the H4, and if there are too many characters then the text can go to the next line.

**CODE SAMPLE**

```
<ul>
<li><h4>H4 Headline</h4> - This is the text that will start on the same line as the headline. This is the text that will start on the same line as the headline. This is the text that will start on the same line as the headline.</li>
<li><h4>H4 Headline</h4> - This is the text that will start on the same line as the headline. This is the text that will start on the same line as the headline. This is the text that will start on the same line as the headline.</li>
<li><h4>H4 Headline</h4> - This is the text that will start on the same line as the headline. This is the text that will start on the same line as the headline. This is the text that will start on the same line as the headline.</li>
</ul>
```

**MOCKUP OF WHAT I NEED EXAMPLE**

[image]

**MOCKUP OF PROBLEM I KEEP GETTING EXAMPLE**
[image]

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is use the following in the CSS part

```
h4{
   display: inline;
}
```